# How to get the commit after a certain commit on a given branch?

Tags: git

If I did

```sh
git checkout master~10
```

how do I find the commit hash of `master~9`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```sh
git rev-list --reverse master | grep -A1 $(git rev-parse HEAD) | tail -n 1
```

but if you're on the latest commit (i.e. you're already on `master`), it will return the current commit as the "next" commit.

Comment: `git rev-list --first-parent --reverse ..master|head -1`

Answer (score 0):

> If I did
>
> ```
> git checkout master~10
> ```
>
> how do I find the commit hash of `master~9`?

Since `git checkout master~10` does not *move* `master`, `master~9` is still `master~9`, and:

```
git rev-parse master~9
```

shows its hash ID directly.  Similarly:

```
git checkout master~9
```

checks it out directly (as another detached HEAD).

I think this is not quite the question you meant to ask.  I think you meant to ask whether it's possible to "move forward one commit" from any arbitrary point in the graph.  The answer is both yes and no: there isn't necessarily a *unique* commit that is one step forward.  For instance:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

If you are currently at commit `G`, "one step forward" is commit `H`, but one step forward from *there* is either commit `I`, or commit `K`, depending on whether you wanted to step towards `branch1` or towards `branch2`.  However, given:

```
       I--J
      /    \
...--H      M--N   <-- master
      \    /
       K--L
```

the answer to the question "which commits are one step forward from H towards `master`" is *both `I` and `K`*.

There are a lot of possible ways to tackle this; which one to use depends on the real problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: "master~9 is still master~9" obviously I know this, it was just another way of saying "the next commit from the current commit". "depending on whether you wanted to step towards branch1 or towards branch2" right, which is why I specified the master branch. You can have a diamond in the commit graph? I thought each commit has one parent.

Comment: Merge commits are those commits with two or more parents. If you have a linear section of graph, the problem is well-defined, though. For tougher cases, consider using `git rev-list --ancestry-path --topo-order --reverse HEAD..<target>` to get a list of commits to visit; save them all somewhere, then visit them, one by one.